# Is returning "const T" from "T::operator+(const T& rhs) const" good practice?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I often see my teachers use `const operator +-*/` which return `const` value. Is it a good practice to do that? Should I do that for every class I write? (`T` means any struct/class that overloads operator +-*/).

For example:

```
struct Fraction
{
    //something here.
    const Fraction operator+(const Fraction &rhs) const;
    const Fraction operator-(const Fraction &rhs) const;
    const Fraction operator*(const Fraction &rhs) const;
    const Fraction operator/(const Fraction &rhs) const;
};
```

Comment: `const Student` in return makes little sense

Comment: It makes little sense to return `const`, and it impedes move semantics.

Comment: Your title is different to your code sample

Comment: For reference: [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: I can sort of understand *multiplying* students (even though the result usually doesn't become a student until years later) but what kind of student do you get if you *divide* one student by another?

Comment: +1 molldbnilo. You should only overload operators when there is a clear unambiguous definition of what the operator means in the domain. I cannot imagine what the different arithmetic operators could do with a pair of input `Student` objects, so make the operations named functions with a meaningful name of what they do.

Comment: I do agree that "Student" made little sense. Changed it to "Fraction".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's a bad idea since it inhibits move semantics. In the following:

```
a = b + c;
```

the temporary result of `b + c` can be moved to `a` if not `const`, but must be copied if it is `const`. Copying is often a more expensive operation than moving.

Historically, in the days before move semantics, it was suggested to prevent nonsense like `(a + b) = c`. Some argued that it was better to make that cause a compile-time error rather than strange run-time behaviour. These days, even if you agree with that argument, doing so comes with a cost.

Comment: There are also ref-qualifiers avaliable if one wishes to prevent `(a+b)=c;`.

Answer (score 2):

The `const` on the return type is **not needed** (in general and in this case). The return is an rvalue, modifying it could make sense, it could not, but in general return types (by value) are not `const`. This is contrasted to returning references, where `const` can make a bigger difference.

Assuming C++11 is being used, the return type being `const Fraction` would **interfere with the usual move semantics**.

When considering the overloading of the arithmetic operators (`+`, `-`, `*` and `/`), following the [**canonical form**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) of the built in operators is recommended. Return the result by modifiable rvalue, i.e. not `const`. For the [**assignment versions**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) of these operators (`+=`, `-=`, `*=` and `/=`), return the value by reference (it would generally be `*this`).

As follows;

```
T T::operator+(const T2 &b) const;
// and
T& T::operator+=(const T2& b);
```

The **`const` on the member methods here make good sense**, the object itself would not be expected to be altered (in a general sense), so marking them as `const` is recommended.